# Pod from StatefulSet stuck in ContainerCreating state - FailedCreatePodSandBox

Tags: kubernetes

Pod controlled by StatefulSet is stuck in `ContainerCreating` state

kubectl get pods

```
md-0                    1/1       Running             0          4h        10.242.208.59   node-5
md-1                    1/1       Running             0          4h        10.242.160.36   node-6
md-2                    0/1       ContainerCreating   0          4h        <none>          node-6
```

kubectl describe pod md-2

```
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
...
Events:
  Type     Reason                  Age               From                                 Message
  ----     ------                  ----              ----                                 -------
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  2m (x68 over 4h)  kubelet, node-6  Failed create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded
```

kubectl describe statefulset md

```
Replicas:           3 desired | 3 total
Pods Status:        2 Running / 1 Waiting / 0 Succeeded / 0 Failed
...
Events:                         <none>
```

kubelet log from node-6

```
RunPodSandbox from runtime service failed: rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded
CreatePodSandbox for pod "md-2_exc(a995dd3d-158d-11e9-967b-6cb311235088)" failed: rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded
createPodSandbox for pod "md-2_exc(a995dd3d-158d-11e9-967b-6cb311235088)" failed: rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded
Error syncing pod a995dd3d-158d-11e9-967b-6cb311235088 ("md-2_exc(a995dd3d-158d-11e9-967b-6cb311235088)"), skipping: failed to "CreatePodSandbox" for "md-2_exc(a995dd3d-158d-11e9-967b-6cb311235088)" with CreatePodSandboxError: "CreatePodSandbox for pod \"md-2_exc(a995dd3d-158d-11e9-967b-6cb311235088)\" failed: rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded"
```

I have two other StatefulSets and they works as expected. For some reason this one is broken.
Also direct `kubectl run` and `docker run` works fine.

**update 2019-01-18**

After restoration of change's timeline I see that this specific pod was deleted with docker command bypassing kubernetes.

Probably this somehow corrupted kubernetes' state or something.

After numerous searching, asking and troubleshooting I still could not find what's exactly wrong. So I had to restart kubelet (`systemctl restart kubelet`) on node where pod was assigned. And the issue is gone.

I hoped to understand how to check what exactly wrong with kubernetes (or kubelet?) but could not find any clues. And kubelet behavior remains black box in this case.

Comment: Can you share docker.log? is docker hung on the node?

Comment: @EytanAvisror currently there is only this

level=info msg="ignoring event" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
level=info msg="shim docker-containerd-shim started" address="/containerd-shim/moby/c89f44d12f912a4f93d5d7a526c65aac0eef8fac2184e9d54ccad9962d7c21e9/shim.sock" debug=false module="containerd/tasks" pid=73580
level=info msg="shim reaped" id=c89f44d12f912a4f93d5d7a526c65aac0eef8fac2184e9d54ccad9962d7c21e9 module="containerd/tasks"

And this messages repeat witch each POD restart.

Comment: @alexar Does 'kubectl logs md-2 -p' return anything more useful ?

Comment: @Nepomucen Nothing useful "Error from server (BadRequest): previous terminated container "md" in pod "md-2" not found", for current pod (kubectl logs md-2) also "Error from server (BadRequest): container "md" in pod "md-2" is waiting to start: ContainerCreating"

Comment: Could you provide a YAML file for your StatefulSet? It looks like the problem totally on the application side. So, you can probably find the solution on the application support site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [alexar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10901442/alexar) mentioned in update:

After restoration of change's timeline I see that this specific pod was deleted with docker command bypassing kubernetes.

Probably this somehow corrupted kubernetes' state or something.

After numerous searching, asking and troubleshooting I still could not find what's exactly wrong. So I had to restart kubelet (systemctl restart kubelet) on node where pod was assigned. And the issue is gone.